# Aligning TextField and Containers in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

I am working on a Flutter project where I have a **text field**. My goal is to place a Container behind each line of text, essentially using it as the background for that line.

However, I am facing an alignment issue. The text doesn't align perfectly within the Container, and they appear misaligned. I want the text to be exactly aligned with the background Container as shown in the image below:

[image]

Here's my current implementation:

```
Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: [
              Builder(builder: (context) {
                int lineLength =
                    textEditingController.text.split('\n').length;
                return ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  itemCount: lineLength,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    final textLine =
                        textEditingController.text.split('\n')[index];

                    final textPainter = TextPainter(
                      text: TextSpan(
                        text: textLine,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: fontSize,
                          fontFamily: 'YekanBakh',
                        ),
                      ),
                      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                    );
                    textPainter.layout(
                      maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    );

                    return Align(
                      child: Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        decoration: textLine.isEmpty
                            ? null
                            : BoxDecoration(
                                gradient: const LinearGradient(
                                  begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                  end: Alignment.centerRight,
                                  colors: [
                                    Colors.purple,
                                    Colors.pink,
                                    Colors.deepOrange,
                                  ],
                                ),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                              ),
                        width: textPainter.width + 10.0,
                        height: textPainter.height,
                        child: Text(
                          textLine,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.transparent,
                            fontFamily: 'YekanBakh',
                            fontSize: fontSize,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
              }),
              IntrinsicWidth(
                child: TextField(
                  scrollPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  controller: textEditingController,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                  maxLines: null,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    height: fontHeight,
                    fontSize: fontSize,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    hintText: 'Text...',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

I suspect the issue might be related to the way I am calculating the text dimensions or aligning the text within the Container. Can someone please guide me on how to resolve this alignment problem?

Thank you in advance!